# Connect HID device to Bluetooth RN42

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth, hid

I'm trying to connect a Wii Remote to an Arduino throw a RN42 bluetooth module. The thing is I'm having troubles pairing them because the pin configuration command needs a String and the Wii Remote's pin is hexadecimal and contains 0x00 which is a String null terminator so I think it could be causing troubles.

I know there is another way (bypassing the pairing) of connecting them that is to use the HID (Human Interface Device) mode of the Wii Remote, but for this I need the module to be a HID host. Does anyone know about this?

I looked about HID mode in the RN42's datasheet but it seems to be to be a HID device and not to connect a HID device to it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that you can't pass the hex-code as String? e.g. `"0x00ABCDEF"`

Comment: In the datasheet it's specified that the syntax of setting the pin is SP,<string> I've tried this code:
  `Serial3.print('S');
  Serial3.print('P');
  Serial3.print(',');
  Serial3.print(0x98);
  Serial3.print(0x21);
  Serial3.print(0xAA);
  Serial3.print(0x1E);
  Serial3.print(0x24);
  Serial3.print(0x00);         
  Serial3.print('\r');`

The thing is that the module accepts the command but then it says the pin is 1523317030360 and when I try to connect to the Wii Remote it says Connect failed.

Comment: Could you link the datasheet? Preferably the function you use.

Comment: This is the datasheet: [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/bluetooth_cr_UG-v1.0r.pdf)
Page 25. Command SP. To the Wii Remote information I'm using [link](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#Bluetooth_Pairing)

Comment: Well, you could try to use `Serial.write()` instead of `Serial.print()`. Am I correct that all commands are terminated by `'\r'`?

Comment: I've also tried Serial.write defining a char array with the command and then sending it like Serial3.write(cmd, sizeof(cmd))

Comment: How did you define cmd? Your `sizeof` looks suspicious.

Comment: char cmd[10];  and then set it char by char

Comment: Do you require pairing? http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#Bluetooth_Pairing